# Smart matrix-creating from complicated csv file

Tags: pandas, numpy, file, matrix, transformation

I have a csv file containing symmetric stress tensors in x, y, z, xy, yz and zx for 500 timepoints that I have imported using pandas. What I need is to create a stress tensor matrix for every single ID at every given timepoint. The picture is a snippet of the file. The real file is [502 rows x 2378 columns]

I have another list of the ID's that I need the matrices for. So I was thinking that the script should iterate through the list of ID's and for each ID, search in the first row for identical suffix (for example ID in the list could be 947951) and then create a 3x3 matrix for every timepoint consisting of the stresses. matrix = [[x,xy,zx],[xy,y,yz],[zx,yz,z]].

Somehow the newly created matrices should still be connected to their ID's because they afterwards have to be rotated based on their ID. If you know how to do rotation of 3x3 matrix for example using numpy functions help would be much appreciated

[image: Stress tensor file]

Comment: Please provide an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), with input and expected output.

Comment: That's too wordy of a question for SO.  If the `pandas` load works, this is no longer a "from csv" question.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it:

```
df_tensors = pd.read_csv('TensorExport500.csv', delimiter=",",skiprows=[0])
print(df_tensors)

# Element ID's from previous coordinateselection to look up stress tensors in LS Dyna data
ID = [947951,948046,948141,948236,948331,12]

# Empty dictinary for appending stress tensors in upcoming for loop
matrices = {}

# Empty list for appending element IDs that are not found in LS Dyna data
IDs_not_in_data = []

# Iteration through ID list for loop up in LS Dyna data
for i in ID:

    # If statement to make sure that all needed stresses are present in LS Dyna data for a given element ID for construction of stress tensor
    if "X-stress-"+str(i) and 'Y-stress-'+str(i) and 'Z-stress-'+str(i) and 'XY-stress-'+str(i) and 'YZ-stress-'+str(i) and'ZX-stress-'+str(i) in df_tensors:

        # Pull out columns of stresses and time for the given element ID and create a temporary dataframe inside iteration used for creating the stress tensor
        temporary_df = df_tensors[['Time','X-stress-'+str(i),'Y-stress-'+str(i),'Z-stress-'+str(i),'XY-stress-'+str(i),'YZ-stress-'+str(i),'ZX-stress-'+str(i)]]

        # Iterates through rows in the temporary dataframe
        for index, row in temporary_df.iterrows():

            # Converts scientific string to float so that numpy library can be applied for tensor/matrix rotation
            x = row[1]
            y = row[2]
            z = row[3]
            xy = row[4]
            yz = row[5]
            zx = row[6]

            # Creates the stress tensor for the given element ID for every timespot and names it "elementid,time" and adds it to matrices dictionary
            matrices[str(i)+","+str(row[0])] = np.matrix([[x,xy,zx],[xy,y,yz],[zx,yz,z]])
    else:
        # Append element ID if the element ID / stresses for the given element ID is not found in the LS Dyna data
        IDs_not_in_data.append(i)

# Function that prints stress tensor of given element at given time if it exist
def get_stresstensor(ID,Time):
    key = str(ID)+","+str(Time)
    matrix = matrices.get(key)
    if key in matrices:
        return "The stress tensor matrix for element ID: " + str(ID) + " at the time: " + str(Time) + " is: \n"  + str(matrix)
    else:
        return "Oh no! The stress tensor of the given element ID: " + str(ID) + " at the time: " + str(Time) + " does not exist because the data could not be found in LS Dyna data."

# Function that lists the element ID's that were not found in the LS Dyna data
def lost_IDs(list):
    if len(list) == 0:
        return "Hurray, stresses for all element ID's were found in the LS Dyna data"
    else:
        return "Oh ship, the following element IDs were not found in LSDyna export file: " + str(list)

print(get_stresstensor("947951","4.9949874665e-05"))
print(lost_IDs(IDs_not_in_data))
```